# Where is `ResFileRefNum` defined?

Tags: macos

I'm trying to get some old C(ish) code to compile but it doesn't define `ResFileRefNum` and I can't seem to find it anywhere in the official header files.

There's a definition in the documentation that degenerates to an `int`, and I can just drop that in if I have to, but I'd rather do it the right way, i.e. `#include` a header that defines the type.

Edit: I found the definition in the header Resources.h in the CarbonCore framework, but seem to be unable to `#include` it in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CarbonCore is a sub-framework within the CoreServices umbrella framework. Just include the main header of that umbrella framework:

```
#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
```